# (Bootstrap 3, CSS) How to change popover width for small-device?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

My `.popover` used CSS:

```
.popover {
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    z-index:1010;
    display:none;
    width:400px;
    max-width:600px;
    padding:1px;
    text-align:left;
    white-space:normal;
    border:1px solid #ccc;
    border:1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    -webkit-border-radius:6px;
       -moz-border-radius:6px;
            border-radius:6px;
    -webkit-box-shadow:0 5px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
       -moz-box-shadow:0 5px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
            box-shadow:0 5px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    -webkit-background-clip:padding-box;
       -moz-background-clip:padding;
            background-clip:padding-box;}

.popover-close {
    color:#FFF;
    font-size:140%;
}

.popover-content a {
    font-size:110%;
}
```

How to change popover width and CSS styles for small-device?

Answer (score 1):

Use media queries:

```
@media (max-width: 768px) {
    .popover {
        /* your stiles here */
    }
}
```

Check [Bootstrap docs](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-intro) about this matter.

Answer (score -1):

write you css in media queries according to your requirement.

```
/* Extra Small Devices, Phones */ 
@media only screen and (min-width : 480px) {

}

/* Small Devices, Tablets */
@media only screen and (min-width : 768px) {

}

/* Medium Devices, Desktops */
@media only screen and (min-width : 992px) {

}

/* Large Devices, Wide Screens */
@media only screen and (min-width : 1200px) {

}
```